Set of Five 5-Digit Numbers Such That Their Fifth Powers Sum Up to the Concatenation of the Numbers
I initially wondered about this while experimenting with my calculator. I found that $12^2+33^2=1233$. Using a quick Python program, I then found $88^2+33^2=8833$. Curious about cubes, I wrote a C program and found these four examples:
$$\begin{align*}
166^3+500^3+333^3 &=166,500,333\\
296^3+584^3+415^3 &=296,584,415\\
710^3+656^3+413^3 &=710,656,413\\
828^3+538^3+472^3 &=828,538,472.
\end{align*}$$
I then searched for fourth powers, which required significant computation time, yielding this result:
$$1485^4+5308^4+5107^4+1603^4=1485,5308,5107,1603$$(Note: Technically, the commas are misplaced, but they make the sequence easier to read.)
Without optimization, approximately 1000 times faster, it would not be feasible for me to find all solutions for fifth powers.
Does a set of five 5-digit numbers exist such that their fifth powers sum up to the concatenation of the numbers?

Interesting question. I doubt that you would be able to find all / disprove the existence of such a set of $5$ $5$-digit numbers without using a program. One thing to note is that $n^5\equiv n\pmod{10}$ so you can rule out many sets of numbers just by checking the last digits of each number.

It is of minor help that at least one of the numbers must be greater than $45370$.

@SaiBhushan I made a typo; that should be $45730$. And if none of them is greater then
$$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5\leq5\times45730^5<10^{24}.$$
A quick brute force search shows that at least one of them must be greater than $46000$. But it is not feasible to brute force all the way up to $10^5$.

Suppose that $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is a sequence of $5$-digit numbers such that $$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5=10^{20}a+10^{15}b+10^{10}c+10^5d+e.$$ Then the respecive  equalities also hold modulo powers of $10$, so we can build the sequence consecutively, beginning form the last digits of its numbers. For the first step, Sai Mehta's observation above implies that the last digit of $e$ can be any, and the sum of the last digits of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ is zero modulo $10$.

I don't see how to solve this problem with a computer without using something like $10^{15}$ operations, which is probably too much to be feasible.  I tried solving using a SAT solver, but unfortunately even finding a sum of 4 fourth powers already took too long, let alone a sum of 5 fifth powers.

this might be helpful

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Signs of the possible solutions.}}$
Let us consider the equation
$$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5=10^{20}a+10^{15}b+10^{10}c+10^5d+e,$$
where
$$a,b,c,d,e\in\left([10^4,10^5-1]\cap\mathbb N\right).\tag{1a}$$
$\color{teal}{\textbf{First sign.}}$
Since
$$(a^5-a)=a(a^2-1)(a^2-4+5)=a(a^2-1)(a^2-4)+5a(a^2-1),$$
then
$\;30\,|\,a^5-a.\;$
Let
$$p=\dfrac1{30}\left(a^5-a+b^5-b+c^5-c+d^5-d+e^5-e\right)\in\mathbb N,$$
then
$$p=\dfrac1{30}\big((10^{20}-1)a+(10^{15}-1)b+(10^{10}-1)c+(10^5-1)d\big)$$
$$=\dfrac1{30}\cdot(10^5-1)\big((10^{15}+10^{10}+10^5+1)a+(10^{10}+10^5+1)b+(10^5+1)c+d\big)$$
$$=\dfrac{33333}{10}\left(\overline{aaaa}+\overline{bbb} +\overline{cc}+d\right)\in \mathbb N,$$
$$\;10\,|\,a+b+c+d,\;\tag{2a}$$
$$a+b+c+d=10s,\quad s\in[4000,39999],\tag{3a}$$
$$p=33333 \left(10000(\overline{aaa}+\overline{bb}+c)+s,\right),\tag{4a}$$
Therefore,
$$33333\,|\, r(a)+r(b)+r(c)+r(d)+r(e),\tag{5a}$$
where
$$r(k)=\dfrac{k^5-k}{30}\, \operatorname{mod} 33333.\tag{6a}$$
$\color{teal}{\textbf{Second sign.}}$
Similarly,
$$30\,|\,(e^5-e),\;30\,|\,(d^5-11^4d),\;30\,|\,(c^5-11^8c),\;30\,|\, (b^5-11^{12}b),\;30\,|\,(a^5-11^{16}a).$$
Then, taking in account $(2a),$
$$q=\dfrac1{30}\left(a^5-11^{16}a+b^5-11^{12}b+c^5-11^8c+d^5-11^4d+e^5-e\right)\in\mathbb N,$$
$$q=\dfrac1{30}\big((10^{20}-11^{16})a+(10^{15}-11^{12})b+(10^{10}-11^8)c+(10^5-11^4)d\big)$$
$$=\dfrac{10^5-11^4}{30}\,\cdot \bigg(\left(10^{15}+10^{10}\,11^4+10^5\,11^8+11^{12}\right)a$$ $$+\left(10^{10}+10^5\,11^4+11^8\right)b+\left(10^5+11^4\right)c+d\bigg)$$
$$=28453\,\cdot \Bigg(\left(10^{14}+10^{9}\,11^4+10^4\,11^8+\dfrac{11^{12}-1}{10}\right)a$$
$$ +\left(10^9+10^4\,11^4+\dfrac{11^8-1}{10}\right)b+\left(10^4+\dfrac{11^4-1}{10}\right)c+s\Bigg).$$
Therefore,
$$28453\,|\, n(a,4)+n(b,3)+n(c,2)+n(d,1)+n(e,0),\tag{7a}$$
where
$$n(k,j)=\dfrac{k^5-11^{4j}\,k}{30}\, \operatorname{mod}28453 .\tag{8a}$$
$\color{brown}{\textbf{Checking algorithm.}}$
Since
$$33333=123\cdot271,$$
then one can get identity in the form of
$$t \,\operatorname{mod} 33333 =(17344(t \,\operatorname{mod}123) + 15590(t\,\operatorname{mod}271))\,\operatorname{mod} 33333 .\tag{1b}$$
Let
$$\begin{cases}
g=271d+e\\[4pt]
d=\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor1{}{g}{271}\\[4pt]
e=g\operatorname{mod} 271,
\end{cases}\tag{2b}$$
then from $(4a)$ should
$$(r(d)+r(e))\,\operatorname{mod} 33333 = (-r(a)-r(b)-r(c)) \,\operatorname{mod} 33333=P(a,b,c).\tag{3b}$$
Let
$$R(271d+e)=(r(d)+r(e))\,\operatorname{mod} 33333,$$
then
$$R(g) = (17344 u_g + 15590 v_g) \operatorname{mod} 33333,\tag{4b}$$
where
$$\begin{cases}
u_g=P(a,b,c)\,\operatorname{mod}123\\[4pt] 
v_g=P(a,b,c)\,\operatorname{mod}271\\[4pt] 
g=0\dots 73440.
\end{cases}\tag{5b}$$
Array $\;u_g\;$ contains $\;123\;$ unique values. So can be built array $\;\mathbb S_u\;$, which contains the sets of all possible indexes $\,g\,$ for every unique value $\;u_g.\;$
Similarly, array $\;v_g\;$ contains $\;271\;$ unique values. So can be built array $\;\mathbb T_v\;,$ which contains the sets of all possible indexes $\,g\,$ for every unique value $\;v_g.\;$
Conjugation $\;\mathbb S_u\cap T_v\;$ defines the sets of possible indexes $\;g\;$ of solutions $(2b).$
This technic allows to build array of sets
$$\;g=\mathbb G_Q,\quad (Q=0\dots 33332)\;$$
for the filtering of possible solutions on the set $(1a)$ for the given $\;a,b,c.\;$ Parameters $\,d,e\,$ can be chosen, taking in account $(2a)$ and $(2b).$
Similarly,
$$28453=37\cdot 769,$$
$$t \,\operatorname{mod} 28453 =(17897(t \,\operatorname{mod}37) + 10767(t\,\operatorname{mod}769))\,\operatorname{mod} 28453 .\tag{6b}$$
and by the described technic is possible additional checking.
Since $10\cdot33333\cdot 28453 > 90000^2,$ then basic complexity of the algorithm is $\;\sim 90000^3\approx 7.3\cdot 10^{14}\;$ of the simple checking operations. This makes the algorithm usable.

@D.W. Improved version is ready.

In the checking algorithm we define e as g mod 271. Is this e different to the e that is from 10000 to 99999?

In Mathematica with n=3
       res =  {x0^3 + x1^3 + x2^3, x0 + x1*10^3 + x2*10^(2*3) }  

FindInstance and Solve are working
   FindInstance[(Subtract @@ res) == 0 && 
           {x0, x1, x2} \[Element] 
           PositiveIntegers && 100 <= {x0, x1, x2 } < 1000, 
         {x0, x1, x2}]

          {{x0->333,x1->500,x2->166}}
        
   Solve[(Subtract @@ res) == 0 && {x0, x1, x2} \[Element] 
        PositiveIntegers && 100 <= {x0, x1, x2 } < 1000, {x0, x1, x2}]

    {{x0->333,x1->500,x2->166},
     {x0->413,x1->656,x2->710},
     {x0->415,x1->584,x2->296},
     {x0->472,x1->538,x2->828}}

By working with Reduce, you find that the solution set is the set of roots for one variable with the others fixed
    Reduce[(Subtract @@ res) == 0] 

     x0==Root[-1000 x1+x1^3-1000000 x2+x2^3-#1+#1^3&,1]||
     x0==Root[-1000 x1+x1^3-1000000 x2+x2^3-#1+#1^3&,2]||  
     x0==Root[-1000 x1+x1^3-1000000 x2+x2^3-#1+#1^3&,3]

So, with Mathematica, the trival algebraically  methods do not work, already with n=4 there is no return after 1 h.
Just to go through tests of all possible numbers of decimal lenght n^2 is an impossible task, even if some large subsets can be eliminated in a fast way.
